# Can we have the option to show titles diff in two lines?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-interface

Sometimes the diff for title edits can be brutal. In this example the title was broken into eight pieces. Or less. Or maybe more. It's difficult to tell:

[image]

Can we "nerf" the diff for titles? Or perhaps add an option to ignore the diff and simply show the two titles side by side (or, better yet, in two separate lines)?